# Where can I find the label map between trained model like googleNet's output to there real class label?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

everyone, I am new to caffe. Currently, I try to use the trained GoogleNet which was downloaded from model zoo to classify some images. However, the network's output seem to be a vector rather than real label(like dog, cat). 
Where can I find the label-map between trained model like googleNet's output to their real class label?
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you got `caffe` from git you should find in `data/ilsvrc12` folder a shell script `get_ilsvrc_aux.sh`.
This script should download several files used for ilsvrc (sub set of imagenet used for the large scale image recognition challenge) training.

The most interesting file (for you) that will be downloaded is `synset_words.txt`, this file has 1000 lines, one line per class identified by the net.
The format of the line is

> nXXXXXXXX description of class

Comment: Hi, I use synset for calculating sort top k predictions from softmax output. Which gives me the top 5 class names. But I dont know how can i calculate its percentage. I mean the top-5 error. Can you kindly guide me

Comment: @khan accuracy layer has a `top_k` parameter. but why don't you post your question as  a real one for everyone to see and respond?

Comment: Ok I will do it now again if you say.

Comment: @Shai Kindly check now. did it